# HTML: Image not displaying to the right of table in html

Tags: html

I have a problem getting an image to the right of my html page. I want to place an image between the top and down labels. currently, I have inserted a few spaces after Label 8 and Label 9, just to show the position of my vertical image. I want an image to show up there instead. I have tried a few things, but the image appears in a different row pushing the other rows to the bottom down.

HTML Code:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
      <td >
       <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
         <td >
          <DIV >
        <table  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8">                               
         <tr>
          <td>
           <table  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td  colspan="2">Hello</td>                                             
            </tr>                                           
            <tr>
                  <td>Label 1</td>                                                     
                  <td>Label 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:550px" colspan='2'>top</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan='2'>Label 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td  colspan='2'>Label 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan='2'>Label 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td  colspan='2'>Label 6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td  colspan='2'>Label 7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td  style="padding-left:25px">Label 8 &nbsp; Label 9</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>      
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr><td> &nbsp; </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td  style="padding-left:550px" colspan='2'>bottom</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td  colspan='2'>footer</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
           </td>
          </tr> 
        </table>
       </DIV>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't see screenshot!

Comment: screenshot plus fiddle please

Comment: Somehow I cannot add any screenshot as this is my first post and it's asking for some 10 reputations. I don't have any :(  You can open the above html  in chrome and see that image should be between top and down labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rowspan` property to have a cell extend on several columns. Then put your image in this cell : http://jsfiddle.net/FLEPb/3/

Comment: rowspan works but it also spaces out the rows. The image spans between top and down labels, so also the rows on the left. I do not want that.

Comment: In this case I can think of two ways : either you ajust the bottom label to place it at the level you want it to, or you create a second table with top-image-bottom and you place it to the right of the first table (like that)[http://jsfiddle.net/FLEPb/4/] (or with floats)